# answers from array must not disappear

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm making this simple exercise but I still have a problem. 
The application lets visitors ask a random question (content doesn't matter), and the visitor gets a random answer back from my array.

**I want the questions and the answers that go with the question to stay.** I want that when the user asks a new question, the previous question and answers are still there. A new question and answer are below the previous one. (unless the visitor refreshes). They currently disappear when a new question is asked. How can I do this, and where do I change the code?

index.html:

```
    <div id="titel">
        <h1>Kom op hier op <span>uiterst betrouwbare manier*</span> te weten hoe jouw levenspad er uit zal zien.</h1>
        <h2>Stel jouw vraag hieronder <i class="arrow down"></i> </h1>
    </div>

        <div id="mijndiv">
                <input type="text" id="mijninput" placeholder="Welke vraag stel je?">
                <button id="button" type="mijnbutton">ZET DE VOORSPELLER IN GANG</button>
                <div id="mijnvoorspelling"></div>
        </div>


        <h3 id="legal">*Wij zijn niet verantwoordelijk voor foutieve voorspellingen.</h3>
```

script.js:

```
let button = document.querySelector("button");
let input = document.querySelector("input");
let voorspelling = ["Dit ziet er niet zo goed uit voor jou.", "Maak je hierover geen zorgen, dit komt goed.", "We zien dit niet meteen goed komen, noch mislukken. Neem het heft in eigen handen en ga ervoor.", "Doe hier iets mee, voor het te laat is.", "Soms moet je even een break nemen, daarna kan je dit aan.", "Dit lukt niet"];

function voorspeller() {

  if (input.value !== "") {
  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * voorspelling.length);
  document.getElementById("mijnvoorspelling").innerHTML = voorspelling[randomNumber];
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", voorspeller);`
```

Comment: the snippets that you provided are not sufficient.

Comment: Can you tell us more on how you want the answers to be saved? And where in your code is a new question asked when the user has given an answer?

Comment: what more should I add?

Comment: The user asks a question in the input field 'mijninput'. The output ('mijnvoorspelling' would then be a random sentence from the array 'voorspelling' + the original question from the user. When the user asks a new question, these steps are repeated but the previous ones remain.

Comment: So the previously asked question and answers have to be stored and displayed somewhere? That you'll eventually end up with a list of asked questions and answers?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Yes, exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your string inside the `<div id="mijnvoorspelling">` element keeps is because you keep resetting it with `..innerHTML = "new answer"`. The easiest solution is to use the `+=` operator instead of `=`. `+=` adds the new string to the first string.

A better way would be to create an element with [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), add the question string to the `innerHTML` of that element and put the new element in the document with [`insertAdjacentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement). This gives you more control on how the output should look and where the output should be put. In this case I've changed your `<div id="mijnvoorspelling">` into a `<ul>` and add each new item as a `<li>` element.

With `insertAdjacentElement` you can pick where you want your element to be inserted. Right now it's set at `'afterbegin'`, which means after the beginning `<ul>` tag, or in other words: at the top. You could change this to `'beforeend'` if you want the output to be placed at the bottom of the list.

```js
let button = document.querySelector("button");
let input = document.querySelector("input");
let mijnVoorspellingen = document.getElementById("mijnvoorspelling");
let voorspelling = ["Dit ziet er niet zo goed uit voor jou.", "Maak je hierover geen zorgen, dit komt goed.", "We zien dit niet meteen goed komen, noch mislukken. Neem het heft in eigen handen en ga ervoor.", "Doe hier iets mee, voor het te laat is.", "Soms moet je even een break nemen, daarna kan je dit aan.", "Dit lukt niet"];

function voorspeller() {
  if (input.value !== "") {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * voorspelling.length);
    let result = `Vraag: ${input.value}.<br> Antwoord: ${voorspelling[randomNumber]}`;
    let listItem = document.createElement('li');
    listItem.innerHTML = result;
    mijnVoorspellingen.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', listItem);
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", voorspeller);
```

```html
<div id="titel">
  <h1>Kom op hier op <span>uiterst betrouwbare manier*</span> te weten hoe jouw levenspad er uit zal zien.</h1>
  <h2>Stel jouw vraag hieronder <i class="arrow down"></i> </h1>
</div>

<div id="mijndiv">
  <input type="text" id="mijninput" placeholder="Welke vraag stel je?">
  <button id="button" type="mijnbutton">ZET DE VOORSPELLER IN GANG</button>
  <ul id="mijnvoorspelling"></ul>
</div>


<h3 id="legal">*Wij zijn niet verantwoordelijk voor foutieve voorspellingen.</h3>
```

Comment: Dankjewel Emiel! This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Graag gedaan. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted for others with the same question

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with your question "I want the questions and the answers that go with the question to stay".

Look if the below function helps. The function appends the questions and answers to the div.

```
function voorspeller() {

    if (input.value !== "") {
        let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * voorspelling.length);
        document.getElementById("mijnvoorspelling").innerHTML += "<b>Vraag:</b> 
        "+input.value+"&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <b>Antwoord:</b> "+voorspelling[randomNumber]+" 
        </br>";
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `+` operators are within the strings. I think they should be `+ "input.value" +`.

Comment: I want that when the user asks a new question, the previous question and answers are still there. A new question and answer are below the previous one.